# Sometimes I am lonely

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Sometimes I feel pretty lonely.

To take the edge off of being so lonely, I joined a book club that my ex belongs to just to be around her some. My brothers wouldn't like that, but they aren't members, so they don't know. The club often only ends up reading the table of contents, preface and/or epilogue.

About my brothers:

The oldest can be a pretty lonely guy too, maybe even lonelier than I am.

The next oldest  has it easy. He's always around people. Sometimes he's outspoken and sometimes he's quiet. I know we all do that from time to time, but he takes it to the extreme! I just laugh about it, but it kind of worries the others; they get all serious about it. They actually called me [facetious](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/facetious)! (I had to look it up.) Even though he's practically a mute, we always know he's there; he's can be a big influence on our behavior.

The long and short of it is that my brothers and I *do* hang out quite a bit, but rarely all at the same time. Then, sometimes when we do, unnoticeably our youngest, whiny, *adopted* brother tries to hang too. We don't really understand why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are

> I

and your brothers are

> the other vowels (and Y, the adopted one), with age denoting alphabetical order.

*Sometimes I feel pretty lonely.*

> Because sometimes "I" stands alone, as a word in its own right.

*To take the edge off of being so lonely, I joined a book club that my ex belongs to just to be around her some. My brothers wouldn't like that, but they aren't members, so they don't know. The club often only ends up reading the table of contents, preface and/or epilogue.*

> What do I and X have in common? Roman numerals, of course! (Which are seldom used for numbering *all* the pages of a book, but often are for small "extra" sections like prefaces.)

*The oldest can be a pretty lonely guy too, maybe even lonelier than I am.*

> A is an even commoner single-letter word than I.

*The next oldest has it easy. He's always around people. Sometimes he's outspoken and sometimes he's quiet. I know we all do that from time to time, but he takes it to the extreme!*

> This may just indicate that the letter E occurs in the words OUTSPOKEN etc. I wonder whether something more is going on here?

*I just laugh about it, but it kind of worries the others; they get all serious about it. They actually called me facetious! (I had to look it up.)*

> SERIOUS contains all the vowels other than A, in order (I wonder whether this might be an error; it seems like what was really wanted here might be a word containing all but E, or all but I. FACETIOUS of course has 'em all.

*Even though he's practically a mute, we always know he's there; he's can be a big influence on our behavior.*

> "Silent E" -- a final letter E that hads no sound in its own right but alters the sound of other vowels preceding it -- is a common feature of the English language.

*The long and short of it is that my brothers and I do hang out quite a bit, but rarely all at the same time.*

> There aren't many words that contain *all* the vowels...

*Then, sometimes when we do, unnoticeably our youngest, whiny, adopted brother tries to hang too.*

> ... but UNNOTICEABLY is one of them. And it has Y in it as well.

*We don't really understand why.*

> "We don't really understand Y."

Comment: I added some info on the book club. The *long and short* of the "serious" sentence was just setting up an excuse for me to use the linked word. :)

Comment: ... Oh, I see. Will edit.

Comment: "The next oldest has it easy....":

 You might have already realised this but this is probably in reference to "e" being the most common letter in the English Alphabet, as well as being silent in some cases (which you do talk about later.)